# Optimal regular expressions representing non-negative integers without leading zeroes except for zero itself

Tags: regex

The only regular expression that I can think of that satisfies the title is

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

I'm sure this is a relatively simple regular expression, but I get the feeling there are more efficient ways of writing it, like maybe using metacharacters. Am I missing anything?

Comment: If you are using a programming language it would be much easier to do this check with a simple variable comparison.  By the way, your regex looks wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the regex is fine--in fact, there's no meaningful way to improve it.  This is as basic as it gets.

Comment: @AlanMoore Sorry, I missed the phrase `without leading zeroes except for zero itself`, and hence I was looking for a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious improvements.  You can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)$
```

but [according to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jR9zY8/1), it does not lead to any speed improvement (6 steps for '0', 8 steps for any other match).

If you just want to show off your regex chops, there's always this:

```
^(0|(?!0)\d+)$
```

It uses negative lookahead 'zero or (not a zero followed by digits)', but that's actually slower (9 steps for any non-zero match).